# Postgresql Update command is too slow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-performance

I have the following postgresql table:

```
CREATE TABLE "initialTable" (
    "paramIDFKey" integer,
    "featAIDFKey" integer,
    "featBIDFKey" integer,
    "featAPresent" boolean,
    "featBPresent" boolean,
    "dataID" text
);
```

I update this table by following command:

```
UPDATE "initalTable" 
SET "dataID" = "dataID" || '#' || 'NEWDATA' 
where 
    "paramIDFKey" = parameterID 
    and "featAIDFKey" = featAIDFKey 
    and "featBIDFKey" = featBIDFKey 
    and "featAPresent" = featAPresent 
    and "featBPresent" = featBPresent
```

As you can see, I am updating the dataID for each row. This update works as an append. It appends new data to the previous ones.

This is too slow. Specially when the "dataID" column gets larger.

Following is the "Explain" results:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on "initialTable"  (cost=4.27..8.29 rows=1 width=974)"
"  Recheck Cond: (("paramIDFKey" = 53) AND ("featAIDFKey" = 0) AND ("featBIDFKey" = 95))"
"  Filter: ("featAPresent" AND (NOT "featBPresent"))"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "InexactIndex"  (cost=0.00..4.27 rows=1 width=0)"
"        Index Cond: (("paramIDFKey" = 53) AND ("featAIDFKey" = 0) AND ("featBIDFKey" = 95) AND ("featAPresent" = true) AND ("featBPresent" = false))"
```

explain ANALYZE:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on "Inexact2Comb"  (cost=4.27..8.29 rows=1 width=974) (actual time=0.621..0.675 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (("paramIDFKey" = 53) AND ("featAIDFKey" = 0) AND ("featBIDFKey" = 95))"
"  Filter: ("featAPresent" AND (NOT "featBPresent"))"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "InexactIndex"  (cost=0.00..4.27 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (("paramIDFKey" = 53) AND ("featAIDFKey" = 0) AND ("featBIDFKey" = 95) AND ("featAPresent" = true) AND ("featBPresent" = false))"
"Total runtime: 13.780 ms"
```

and the version:

```
"PostgreSQL 8.4.14, compiled by Visual C++ build 1400, 32-bit"
```

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Please add `explain analyze` etc, per http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info ... and the *full* `update` statement.

Comment: Please add `explain ANALYZE`, so we can see what is actually happening in addition to what the planner *expects* to happen.  The rest of the information requested on the page cited by Craig helps, too.

Comment: I added the exlpain analyze as well

Comment: The EXPLAIN ANALYSE says the query takes less than 1 millisecond. How fast did you expect it to be?

Comment: It says it takes 13.780 ms. And this is too much for just 1 query.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not at all convinced this is a real problem.  If 15ms is too long for a single query, you need to start and ask if you are optimizing prematurely and if it is really the bottleneck.  If it is, you may want to reconsider how you are using your database.  Keep in mind that queries can execute faster than explain analyze suggsts (I have seen some queries run 4x slower under EXPLAIN ANALYZE).  So start by profiling your application and look for real bottlenecks.

This being said, if you do find this is a bottleneck you could take a close look at what is indexed.  Too many indexes slow down write operations and that is implicated in update queries.  This may mean adding a new index with all columns in the update, and removing other indexes as needed.  However, I really don't thin you are going to get a lot more out of that query.